# Indy TCP SSL Multithread

Tags: delphi, indy

I am developing application that use IdTCPClient for exchanging binary data. I create thread for reading data socket but for sending data using Main Thread. It works fine. 
But when I use SSL sometimes it works, but sometimes (very often) error occured randomly. I have the following errors

- SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
- block cipher pad is wrong

How can i solve this problem

Comment: You could start by adding a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your q.

Comment: A single IdTCPClient cannot be shared between threads.  *"It works most of the time"* does not mean it isn't broken.  Consolidate your reads and writes into a single thread.

Comment: @J... "*A single IdTCPClient cannot be shared between threads*" - that is not true at all. It is perfectly valid/common to share a connection with multiple threads, do reads in one thread and writes in another thread. What you do need to avoid is doing reads in multiple threads, or writes in multiple threads (without adequate syncing, anyway). I suspect the OP is likely doing reads in multiple threads, corrupting the inbound data. "*Consolidate your reads and writes into a single thread*" - that is not necessary.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Fair enough - more accurate to say that you can't share a client between threads *without consideration*.  As Martyn said, we need a [mcve].

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the suggestion, I just found the root cause of the problem, this happens when there are 2 different threads that access the socket to write simultaneously. So I decided to queuing all the processes that will write to the socket.